# How to divide a table into two parts with headings Ag Grid Angular

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am working on a project with ag-grid and I want to make a user table which shows all roles and departments access in the same table like this:

```
| Permisssions |    transactions    |   inventory   |   orders
|--------------|------------------------------------------------  
| Departments  |
|--------------|------------------------------------------------
| depart1      |      xxx                 xxx           xxx
| depart2      |      xxx                 xxx           xxx
| depart3      |      xxx                 xxx           xxx
|              |
|----------------------------------------------------------------
| Roles
|----------------------------------------------------------------
| roles1       |      xxx                 xxx           xxx
| roles2       |      xxx                 xxx           xxx
| roles3       |      xxx                 xxx           xxx
|              |
```

I can't find anything in the docs related to this. As you can see in the example above, the table is divided into two parts.

- Departments
- Roles

Each having its own subheading and also the column names and rows will be dynamic. Kindly let me know how to achieve this. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The closest I can think of is using [Aligned Grids](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-aligned-grids/#demonstration-example)

You basically define 2 ag-grids but you can synchronize the actions taken on either of the grids.

```
gridOptionsFirst = {
    // some grid options here
        ...
};

gridOptionsSecond = {
    // register first grid to receive events from the second
    alignedGrids: [gridOptionsFirst]

    // other grid options here
    ...
}
```

From the example in docs,

1. you can define a `headerHeight` of 0 for bottom grid
2. add a `<span> Roles </span>` between 2 grids
3. give cellStyle to Transaction,  inventory, orders columns to remove the borders

and produce something like this

```
| Departments  |  
| Permisssions | transactions    |   inventory   |   orders  
|--------------------------------------------------------------    
| depart1      |      xxx                 xxx           xxx  
| depart2      |      xxx                 xxx           xxx  
| depart3      |      xxx                 xxx           xxx  
|----------------------------------------------------------------  
| Roles  
|----------------------------------------------------------------  
| roles1       |      xxx                 xxx           xxx  
| roles2       |      xxx                 xxx           xxx  
| roles3       |      xxx                 xxx           xxx
```

Comment: close but not really what i want. I want the permissions to be on the top and departments as a sub heading similarly roles as well